# Elementaryos Hera couldn't remove default elementaryos apps

Tags: files, default

I couldn't be able to remove the default files app of elementary. whenever I from terminal it says

> E: Unable to locate package io.elementary.files
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'io.elementary.files'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'io.elementary.files'

and in appcenter it says

> Application state not set as installed in AppCenter for package: Files

Comment: What app are you trying to remove and how? What command you type in terminal to remove the app?

Answer (score 0):

**How to remove any package from the system using terminal.**

Proper way is to type in terminal :

```
sudo apt purge nameoftheapp
```

Comment: that doesn't work either in my case it is io.elementary.files I tried everything for some reason my default applications broken. It says there no io.elementary.files app but clearly I can see it and launch it.

Comment: Why you want to remove the crucial part of the system? https://github.com/elementary/files

Comment: there are some bugs like (couldn't show the icons of my .mat file folder, It sometimes couldn't recognize my plugged in storage device and search functionality is not as powerful as nautilus) thats why I would like to make nautilus as my default file manager. even though I choose nautilus as my default files app, firefox keeps opening downloaded files from the io.elementary.file app which makes me really want to remove the app

Comment: Also I just tested I couldn't remove any default elementary app. For example I dont use calendar which I dont needed. whenever I try to uninstall it gives me same error as the default files app

Comment: I provided the tutorial how to install the Elementary OS App Center. The same way you need to reinstall files.

Comment: Corrected tutorials just because I do not believe people that they will do everything correctly. That is why I decided to provide detailed tutorials. One is how to install app center, the second one is for files. Install both directly repeating steps (commands) one by one I provided in both tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

**How to install the Elementary OS App Center**

Install dependcies:

```
sudo apt install -y libaccountsservice-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgranite-dev libgtk-3-dev liblightdm-gobject-1-dev libwingpanel-2.0-dev libx11-dev meson valac libmutter-2-0 libmutter-2-dev libcanberra-dev libcloudproviders-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libgail-3-dev libgee-0.8-dev libglib2.0-dev libnotify-dev libpango1.0-dev libplank-dev libsqlite3-dev libunity-dev libzeitgeist-2.0-dev libappstream-dev gettext libflatpak-dev libhandy-0.0-dev libjson-glib-dev libpackagekit-glib2-dev libpolkit-gobject-1-dev libsoup2.4-dev libxml2-dev libxml2-utils libhandy-0.0 libpackagekit-glib2-dev appstream-util
```

Update the system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Type following commands in terminal one by one:

```
cd 
cd Downloads
wget https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd appcenter-master
meson build --prefix=/usr 
cd build 
ninja
sudo ninja install io.elementary.appcenter
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately it didn't work out. after using "ninja" it gave me an error " warning: `AppStream.ProvidedKind.MIMETYPE' is deprecated. Use MEDIATYPE"  
I had 3 more warning like this ("`Gtk.Dialog.get_action_area' has been deprecated since 3.12" "implicit .begin is deprecated"   "`Gtk.Dialog.get_action_area' has been deprecated since 3.12"). Eventhough I had the error I still tried to install the appcenter but ended up having  "ninja: error: unknown target 'io.elementary.appcenter'
"

Comment: Reload the thread , check corrected tutorials. Install dependencies.
Warnings are not important in this case.

Comment: If this will not solve the issue, then reinstall the whole Elementary OS system from the scratch using the newest iso file from here: https://elementary.io just type 0 and then click download. Download also Balena Etcher from here: https://www.balena.io/etcher/ Install it and then make bootable usb drive with the downloaded iso.

Comment: By the way do not remove default apps, because you will damage the system.

Comment: I did it on my old laptop  which was running elementaryos and nothing break after doing that. I only had this issue on my new laptop. I am having this issue for the first time

Comment: Reinstall the system on new laptop the way I described. Default apps are integrated with the system. If you want you can learn how to install and build Linux from scratch, or install Gentoo and make it the way you want. When you will reinstall the system and will have any issue, make new thread and describe it step by step.

Comment: I removed default calendar app, videos etc. before which I wasn't using at the time. Which I didn't touch app center no worries on that part. BTW I appriciate your help but it seems something is really broken in some other apps also

Comment: I see. Yes, you are absolutely right. I do not know what you exactly did. You can even type the history in terminal and review and analyze your commands you typed. I can only guess that when you removed something it has broke another package(s), config(s) and this may be related to the errors you provided above. Really hard to say. I think I would rather try to reconsider reinstalling the system. Then make a snapshot or a backup with timeshift  or something like that before you will remove anything. And then remove one thing, make a backup , remove next thing. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

**How to install Elementary OS Files App.**

Install dependcies:

```
sudo apt install -y libaccountsservice-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgranite-dev libgtk-3-dev liblightdm-gobject-1-dev libwingpanel-2.0-dev libx11-dev meson valac libmutter-2-0 libmutter-2-dev libcanberra-dev libcloudproviders-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libgail-3-dev libgee-0.8-dev libglib2.0-dev libnotify-dev libpango1.0-dev libplank-dev libsqlite3-dev libunity-dev libzeitgeist-2.0-dev libhandy-0.0 libpackagekit-glib2-dev appstream-util
```

Update the system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then in terminal type:

```
cd 
cd Downloads
wget https://github.com/elementary/files/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd files-master
meson build --prefix=/usr 
cd build 
ninja
sudo ninja install io.elementary.files
```